# installed wrong libc6 package and broke system

Tags: debian, apt, glibc

## Background

I was attempting to upgrade my libc6 version in a "not" nice way. It all started with me trying to update my MariaDB from 10.1 to 10.2. I somehow then managed to find out that libc6=1.24 that was installed, was not good enough, and that it required libc6=1.27. I managed to break my installation, when I used `dpkg -i` on a downloaded package here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/ (specifically *libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb*). I allowed it to automatically deconfigure my other packages, and this is when I know I ruined it.

My system is running

```
root@redfox:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:    9.13
Codename:   stretch
```

## Current issue

Now, whenever i try to use dpkg, or try to run `apt-get upgrade` I run in to missing programs and also having missing / broken dependencies. Here is output:

```
root@redfox:~# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cups-core-drivers hplip-data libart-2.0-2 libcupscgi1 libgutenprint2 libsane-hpaio python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-ptyprocess
  python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  hplip libgcc1:i386 printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 4370 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
root@redfox:~# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

## What have I done to try to fix it?

I have attempted to downgrade to libc6 version 1.24 again, but I am not sure if that worked out too well. I have also tried to clear package cache, autoclean etc, but I am unfortunately quite stuck on where to go next. I have tried to research what I can do, but it is hard to understand as I feel this is a very specific problem to my state, unfortunately.

### Edit #1

I have tried to `cp /bin/true /sbin/ldconfig`, as I found that `/sbin/ldconfig` was missing. However, it seems like the system is even more damaged than first assumed. Here is output when i try to install packages suggested in the answer of Stephen Kitt below:

```
sudo dpkg -i libc-bin_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb locales_2.24-11+deb9u4_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libc-bin.
(Reading database ... 202484 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc-bin_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package locales.
Preparing to unpack locales_2.24-11+deb9u4_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc-bin:
 libc-bin depends on libc6 (>> 2.24); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libc-bin depends on libc6 (<< 2.25); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.27-3ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of locales:
 locales depends on libc-bin (>> 2.24); however:
  Package libc-bin is not configured yet.
 libc6:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1) breaks locales (<< 2.27) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of locales to be configured is 2.24-11+deb9u4.

dpkg: error processing package locales (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
 locales
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to re-install all the libc-related packages, in particular [`libc6`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libc6) itself, [`libc-bin`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libc-bin), [`locales`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/locales), and [`libc-l10n`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libc-l10n):

```
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-bin_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/locales_2.24-11+deb9u4_all.deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-l10n_2.24-11+deb9u4_all.deb
dpkg -i libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb libc-bin_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb locales_2.24-11+deb9u4_all.deb libc-l10n_2.24-11+deb9u4_all.deb
```

Check your `PATH` too (see the last error message shown in your question).

Since your `/sbin/ldconfig` is gone, you’ll need to fudge things a little to get `dpkg` to install the packages:

```
cp /bin/true /sbin/ldconfig
```

This will allow `dpkg` to proceed enough to get the real `ldconfig` installed.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I am however sure that my path is correct (I tried to set the path env as I run the command as well to make sure) and as well as checking .bashrc.
I am afraid that the bin is actually missing, as in the program it uses, does not exist. Echoing `$PATH` returns the following: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`. That again means that I am unable to use dpkg to install the packages you suggested. EDIT: I realise that /sbin is not present. Will try that now.

Comment: Your `PATH` is incorrect if you checked it as root (as indicated by the prompts in your question): it must include `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` for root (`ldconfig` is in `/sbin`).

Comment: Thank you again. I sourced an updated file in /root/.bashrc, now including: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`. I do apologise if this is a very trivial problem, but I don't understand why it doesn't catch. I have also tried to run `echo $PATH` as root and my change is present. Do I need to do anything extra to let dpkg aware of this `$PATH`? EDIT: I just checked manually in /sbin and the program is not present.

Comment: See the update, you can cheat a bit for `ldconfig`. Your changes are good enough for `PATH`.

Comment: Awesome, seems like more is broken. I added my output to the question under "Edit #1".

Comment: OK, I thought you’d downgraded libc6; see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `apt-get upgrade -f` -f tries to fix missing or broken packages. If this does not succed, please post full output.

futher options when automatic fix fails:

- Locate broken packge and try to remove it and then reinstall it by sources.
- Check `echo $PATH` to make sure it contains the correct locations.

Tip: If you need new packages for debian do not use ubuntu packages. these may work, but have a high chance breaking the system. A better source for a debian system are the packages from the unstable / testing branch of debian. An other Option is to use the "backports". These packages require as few new libs as possible for much newer Version of the target software.

Comment: The question shows that `-f` has already been tried.

Comment: But the output is incomplete. Process was aborted, before a meaningfull error was given.